# Eclipse not building properly

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

Okay so basically I'm working on recursion. And I recently switched from a mac to a PC, so I'm now using eclipse instead of XCode for programming c++. now this has happened to me a couple times, and I still have no idea why its doing it. When this happens I do not get an error code, I've searched far and wide for this solution but haven't found one yet, so i'm hoping you guys could help. So everything was going great (almost finished), but i realized a bug, so I fix it, then I save it, then I build it, run it, then it doesn't build properly (i'm assuming), like it didn't build my new code, it just rebuilt my old code and ran that, im using MinGW, I've also tried to import my old code via copy and paste, but it did the same thing, please help.

*let me know if I left anything out that might be needed to know

**update on my project file it does have a error sign on it, but there isn't one in my code

***update update I looked through the errors and found that it doesnt have permission to open output file "recursive.exe" (my project name)

Comment: `recursive.exe` is probably still running, check the task manager if you can't see it.

Comment: Make sure you have the administrative privilege on your Eclipse and all files that you might need to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

OK solution: run eclipse as admin